# how to connect API with flutter Dio

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to connect the below API into my flutter code. but I'm getting below error. how to solve this. appreciate your help on this.

> I/flutter (15198): null I/flutter (15198):
> {"success":false,"code":210,"status":"Unauthorized","msg":"You are not
> authorized to visit this route"}

[image]

```
Map<String, String> loginUserData = {
  'email': '',
  'password': '',
  'id': '',
  'userName': '',
  'token': '',
  'userStatus': '',
  'wallet_address': '',
};

@override
void initState() {
  _Unlockchallenge();
  //dynamic.initState();
  asyncMethod();
}

void asyncMethod() async {
  await _Unlockchallenge();
}

Future _Unlockchallenge() async {
  var response;
  print(response);
  try {
    response = await Dio().get(BASE_API + "challenge/getChallengeByUserAndType/calories",
        options: Options(headers: {
          'Authorization':loginUserData["token"], //HEADERS
        }

        ));

    print(response);

  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    //throw Exception('Unable to get data');
  }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the api is receiving the request with the proper model for the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

the header need to be like this

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer ${loginUserData["token"]}'
```

Comment: now it display http 500 error

Comment: and the message is it "server internal error" ? maybe your miss send some data in the body
```
Map<String, String> loginUserData = {
  'email': '',
  'password': '',
  'id': '',
  'userName': '',
  'token': '',
  'userStatus': '',
  'wallet_address': '',
};
```
your sending empty data also make sure you filled this data.